# Is modifying a function in derived class and accessing it by derived class object itself an example of runtime polymorphism

Tags: c++, oop, overriding, virtual-functions, run-time-polymorphism

I was reading about **function overriding** and **run-time polymorphism** online.

While reading I found an example of function overriding on [programiz](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/function-overriding) where following example was given :

```
// C++ program to demonstrate function overriding

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
   public:
    void print() {
        cout << "Base Function" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
   public:
    void print() {
        cout << "Derived Function" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived derived1;
    derived1.print();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Derived Function
```

Here in `Derived` class we have modified `print()` function of `Base` class and is accessed by an object `derived1` of the derived class.

A question stuck in my mind - is this an example of ***runtime polymorphism*** also? or
operator overriding not always comes under runtime polymorphism as I have read this somewhere

> The main use of virtual function is to achieve Runtime Polymorphism.Runtime polymorphism can be achieved **only** through a pointer (or reference) of base class type.

Hence my question is - "Is this an example of run-time polymorphism as does not use the `virtual` keyword and involves a *pointer to base class* and even an example of function overriding?

Correct me if I have mentioned anything wrong.

Comment: _"is this an example of runtime polymorphism also?"_ No, _runtime polymorphism_ requires the `Base::print()` function to be `virtual`.

Comment: No, it's not an override, since `Base::print` is not virtual. There are two independent, unrelated functions `Base::print` and `Derived::print`. In particular, `Derived derived1; Base* p = &derived1; p->print();` would call `Base::print`; whereas if `print` were virtual, this would have called `Dervied::print` (that's the whole point of polymorphism). Neither class in your example is a polymorphic class; there is no polymorphism at all.

Comment: Polymorphism requires two things: First that the functions are *virtual*; Second is that you use pointers (or references) to the *base* class. For example `Base *base = new Derived;` and then declare `print` as `virtual`.

Comment: Think about when the decision on which function to call is made. Unless the functions are virtual the decision is made by the compiler at compile-time. Only with virtual functions is a choice made at run-time.

Comment: @ShailavMalik Well there are no operators involved, but neither is it function overriding. Overriding is generally understood to mean a choice made at run time using. in C++, virtual functions. So, no, it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not runtime polymorphism.

The site doesn't claim that either, but it is using the term "*override*" incorrectly (or at least not with the usual technical meaning). Only `virtual` functions can be overridden and then the override provides runtime polymorphism.

What the site is demonstrating is simply (compile-time static) name lookup rules of class members. No polymorphism or overriding. C++ simply allows entities with the same name in different namespaces and classes and has rules on how to decide which of these a given expression names. These entities are not related at all. For example you can have a static data member `static int mem;` in a base class and a non-static member function `void mem();` in a derived class. If you write `obj.mem` it will either be the static data member (if `obj`'s *static* type is the base class) or the non-static member function (if `obj`'s *static* type is the derived class). These obviously have nothing to do with one another.